# Order of elements of a quotient group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $A$ be the (normal) subgroup of $B$. $A$ is generated by all elements $x^7$ with $x\in B$. Show that every element in $B/A$ has order $1$ or $7$. I do not really have a clue where to start or if this is even true. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any element in the quotient group $B/A$ is of the form $xA$ such that $x\in B-A$. Now consider $(xA)^7=x^7A$, by the definition of $A$, $x^7 \in A$, therefore $(xA)^7=A$. Note that $A$ is the identity of the quotient group $B/A$. Thus order of $xA$ is a divisor of $7$, so it is either $1$ or $7$.

Comment: Thanks, I do see the point indeed. Put suppose $x$ has order $2$, then $(xA)²=x²A=A$. So there is an element with order not equal to $1$ or $7$. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: So when you consider the coset $xA$ you are assuming $x \not\in A$. Suppose $x$ as order $2$ then $x^7=x^6.x=x$. But you are given $x^7 \in A$ for every $x \in B$, this will make $x \in A$ (A contradiction).

Comment: Exactly what I was overseeing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
Consider what are the elements of $B/A$.

Next consider what happens to those elements if you take their $7$th power.

Last consider that $7$ is a prime number.